# Using toggle in shinyjs to initially hide an element and them make it appear with actionlink()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny app in which I am trying to initially hide a plot in tabPanel and then have it appear when a link is clicked using a combination of actionlink() and shinyjs::toggle. I have it working to make the plot appear and disappear when the text is selected but I can not figure out how to make the plot hidden until the text is selected. Currently the plot disappears when the text is selected.

```
ui<- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = T),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(tb),
    tags$style(HTML('body {font-family:"EksellDisplay-Medium"};
                    src: "EksellDisplay-Medium.otf"')),
    fluidRow(
      useShinyjs(),
      tabBox(title = "Coming Clean",
                 height = "250px",
                 side = "right",
                 id = "id",
                 tabPanel(title = paste0("Impact: ", lca_sum_970$kgCO2e, "kgCO2"),
                          "Carbon emission and water use of producing the garment. By using organic materials our products emit 25% less carbon an use 66% less water on average.",
                          highlight = "black",
                          actionLink("show_lca", "Take a look"),
                          plotOutput(outputId = "lca_plot")),
                 tabPanel(title = paste0("Traceability: ", mean(trac$Traceability), "%"),
                          "Cut, Sewn, dyed, and knitted in Los Angeles CA. Cotton farming in Central India",
                          plotOutput(outputId = "trac_plot"),
                          style = "padding-bottom:0px"),
                 tabPanel(title = paste0("Cost: ","$", sum(cost_970$Value)),
                          "Our clothing is not cheap and there is a reason for that. We opt for domestic manufacturing which increases our costs compared to overseas production as shown below. We choose to do this because we want to support the domestic textile industry and be close to our supply chain",
                          plotOutput(outputId = "cost_plot")))
      ))
  )

server<- function(input, output, session){

output$lca_plot<- renderPlot({carbon_plot})
  
  observeEvent(input$show_lca, {
     toggle("lca_plot")
    })

}
```

Comment: You are using `environment`-variables that you did not provide in your example. Your code is not reproducible. Please edit your post according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

If you want the initial state to be hidden, try

```
hidden(plotOutput(outputId = "lca_plot"))
```

Then you will start with hidden plot, and display once you click on the action link.